# Stylizing the radio buttons Using cardview in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-cardview

I am using radio buttons in a radio group -It works perfectly

```
   <RadioGroup
    android:layout_below="@id/textview_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/radgrp">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_1"
        android:text="option"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_2"
        android:text="option"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="option"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_4"
        android:text="option"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

But whenever I try to use some styling by surrounding the radio buttons by the cardview- The radio group loses all its functionality..
I am talking about the situation when I use the following code -

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_below="@id/textview_question"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:id="@+id/radgrp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton_1"
    android:text="option"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton_2"
    android:text="option"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="option"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/radiobutton_4"
    android:text="option"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RadioGroup>
```

Now here is the problem how do I stylize the Radio buttons by giving them an aero feel like cardview..As the above code is crating problem in the functionality of the Radio group(erros includes- Non working of `clearCheck()` method and also multiple check occuring..etc).
Please help me to style the radio buttons in my desired way (i.e. giving each radio button a card like feel)

Comment: instead of place radio button in cardview try to give background of your need to radiobutton

Comment: Do not add radiobutton inside cardview while they are child is radiogroup .look for how to customize radio button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different radio buttons of the same radio groups in different `cardview` layouts will not work. So your approach is wrong. Instead you can try placing `textview` along with a single radio button. And in the Java code you can check which one is checked **and** even disable other radio buttons. **And** this is only the simplest way you can achieve your goal following your approach.